# Where can I find documentation on XCM channels ( HRMP, VMPs). How they actually work?

Tags: xcm, xcmp

Although I can read the code and try to bring the pieces together but If I can find the documentation or specification implementation doc on XCM channels,

how they are implemented, how it ensures the message passed is actually delivered, understanding the message queue and how are the messages included in parachain PVFs.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful for you.
https://docs.astar.network/docs/learn/xcm/integration/hrmp/
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-hrmp-channels

or tru to check Polkadot Forum for such a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I found this official documentation and a good material.
https://paritytech.github.io/xcm-docs/